# Vue can't access in public ip

Tags: vue.js, webpack, server, portforwarding

I've set `vue.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: ".",
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 8080,
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
};
```

When I run `npm run serve`, I can open it on localhost, but not with my public ip `125.xxx`.

I've setted up my router to port forward `80` to `192.168.x.x:8080`.

As you can see, it said Javascript is not enabled.

**It's worked with plain HTML.**

**It's worked with Backend Express**

**Only vue not worked**
[image: Javascript not enabled.]

Comment: My guess it is that it has something to do with the port.  Have you tried setting the port to 80 and then port forwarding port 80 on your router to 192.168.x.x ?

Comment: @abaga129
Public port is 80,
Private port is 8080 (Vue default).

I've tried it with Live Server (VSCode extension) to serve on port 5500.
Which is work. I've tried the same for vue with port 5500, still didn't work.

My guess it's the vue problem.